# One bug maybe because shutil

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

What is wrong with the line with **? The "print" above works correctly.

```
import os
import time
import shutil


def trace_pdf_ppt(directory):
    try:
        flag = False
        assert os.path.isdir(directory)
        target = os.path.join('/Users/yanlu/Desktop/',               "pptPdf"+time.strftime('%Y%m%W'))
        print("target", target)
        if not os.path.exists(target):
            os.mkdir(target)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory, topdown=True):
            for fl in files:
                print(fl)
                if fl.split('.')[-1] == "pdf" or fl.split('.')[-1] ==    'ppt' or fl.split('.')[-1] == 'pptx':
                    print("copy successfully")
                    **shutil.copy(fl, target)**

                    flag = True
        if not flag:
            print("No ppt or pdf.")
        return target

    except:
        print("Trace Error")
        return ''
```

Comment: How does it not work? Are you getting an error message? If so, what is it? To get more details on the error you could remove the `try-except` since that will catch any errors and just print `Trace Error`.

Comment: Please add the stack trace and more information about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: No， there is no error message, but I guess there is something wrong with this line. Because I add "print" above and below this line, the one above worked correctly and the one below didn't work.

Comment: I want to write a program that can help me backup my ppt&pdf every week. And this part is a function to trace the source directory and find all the ppt&pdf files.